# str.title() заменяет букву на заглавную после _ (Python)

Tags: python, строки

Маленький вопрос насчёт `str.title()`. Я знаю, что данная функция заменяет первые буквы в словах на заглавную.

Просто текст: `this is a text`
Текст с title: `This Is A Text`

Но в нём есть проблема. Если, например, у меня текст это `this_is`, то title сделает так: `This_Is`. А я не хочу, чтобы после символов он заменял буквы на заглавную.

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: В python метод stri.title() расценивает символы и цифры внутри слова как разделители. Если у вас только одно слово с символом - используйте str.capitalize().

Comment: если несколько слов в строке то лучше сделать это регуляркой `result = re.sub(r"\b\w", lambda match: match.group().upper(), str)` где `str` первоначальная строка `\w` - обозначает цифры буквы и подчеркивание, таким образом `пример_строки` преобразует только `П` так как перед подчеркиванием нет границы слова `\b`

Comment: @strawdog Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вот так:

```py
string = "this_is a text"

print(" ".join([s.capitalize() for s in string.split()]))
```

Вывод:

> This_is A Text